# azure event hub logging policy context filtering?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-api-management

Azure Event Hub Logging has a policy configuration which defines the information that gets logged downstream. I've set up an IEventProcessor listener which gets a handle to all of the EventData configured in the policy. I could write code in IEventProcessor to log this data through a company-specific logger.  I could also write code in my IEventProcessor to skip additional logging if context.LastError.Reason = "OperationNotFound".

Is there a way to configure filters in the policy to handle this type of logic that would prefilter events that I want to log or don't want to log? Also, is there a way to programmatically do this through some type of pre-event handler? By the time my IEventProcessor listener implementation is reached, I'm assuming that the event has already been logged somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [choose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/azure/dn894085.aspx#choose) policy and putting the `<logtoeventhub>` policy inside the choose.